# Go to certain position in website using event Listener

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, tabs, dom-events

I want to after pressing tab button move to certain position in my website I have event listener `(keydown.Tab)="onKey($event)` which should trigger function after pressing tab, but I haven't got any idea how to make same effect as clicking on href but with tab.

Comment: You don't need JS for this, see [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute. If you want to navigate to a tabbed link immediately, you've to combine tabindex attributes and `focusin` event. `focusin` fires when an element within the tabindexing gains the focus, you can then activate the link in focusin handler.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Anchor links:

```
<a href="#Target">Button</a>
<div id="Target"> The target element you want to jump to</div>
```